# Horizontal hierarchy chart in Visio from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-visio

I can create a vertical hierarchy chart in Visio from Excel data. Thing is, I need a horizontal (left to right) chart. Is it possible to create?
If not, as a workaround, I rotated the chart, but now I should rotate each and every object in it as well.

I have used [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/create-organization-chart-in-visio-2010-from-excel-spreadsheet/) tutorial.

I am using Windows 7, Office 2010, Visio 2010.

My other problem is that Visio messes up the hierarchy. Check this diagram out to understand:

[image]

This is the used excel data:

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of your data? Also excel and visio 2007 or 2010? What OS?

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider are the **Rotate Diagram** commands: On the **Home** tab, look under **Position > Orient Shapes > Rotate Diagram**. There are several commands that change the layout of an existing org chart.

[image]

For example, if this is the original org chart.

[image]

Then using **Rotate Left** will transform it as shown below.

[image]

Comment: This could be a workaround, however, all the lines get messed up. I have to manually move all the lines and the boxes as well, which is not the way it should be.